# QImage and its const bits() const method

Tags: qt

Qt's QImage has two methods:

```
uchar* QImage::bits();
const uchar* QImage::bits() const;
```

But how to call a second one? Calling

```
const uchar* p = image.bits();
```

Will call a non-const version O_O.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const QImage* im = &image;
const uchar* p = im->bits();
```

will use the const version.